# How to import a method which is in wheel file in databricks notebook?

Tags: python, databricks, python-wheel

Hi I am trying to import a method which is in wheel file for that I am installing it and when I am using this code

```
! pip install date_util-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
from date_util-1.0-py2.py3-none-any import add_executiondate
```

I am getting error as invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

in the `from` statement you need to use the name of the package inside the wheel, but you're using the file name (`date_util-1.0-py2.py3-none-any`), and it's not a valid Python identifier that is expected by Python

Answer (score 0):

usually I add the wheel file from "Compute Cluster" , "Libraries" , "install new"

then I drop the file, as per the below screen shot, this way you do not need to install the package everytime your cluster got restarted.

just need to do so, then import your package the normal way

[image]